# Show that it is/is not a normal extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a^4=5$. Show that:

1. $\mathbb{Q}(ia^2)$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.
2. $\mathbb{Q}(a+ia)$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}(ia^2)$
3. $\mathbb{Q}(a+ia)$ is not a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

I have done the following:

1. $Irr(ia^2, \mathbb{Q})=x^2+5$

The splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(ia^2)$.

Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(ia^2)$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

2. $Irr(a+ia, \mathbb{Q}(ia))=x^2-2ia^2$

The splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(a+ia)$.

Therefore, $\mathbb{Q}(a+ia)$ is a normal extension of $\mathbb{Q}(ia^2)$.

3. $Irr(a+ia, \mathbb{Q})=x^4+20$

Are the solutions $\pm \sqrt{2i}a, \pm \sqrt{-2i}a$ ??

These solutions are not in $\mathbb{Q}(a+ia)$, are they?? How can we prove it??

Is this correct??

Comment: What’s a canonical extension? Oh, you probably mean a [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension) extension!

Comment: @k.stm I edited my post... It should be "normal" instead of "canonical"...

Comment: It will clarify things for you if you figure out what $\sqrt{2i}$ actually is.

Comment: @user204305 Do you mean that since $i=e^{\pi i}$, it stands that $\sqrt{2 i}=\sqrt{2 e^{\pi i}}=\sqrt{2} e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}$?? Is it correct??

Comment: You have that wrong. $i$ is not $e^{\pi i}$.

Comment: @user204305 Yes, I am sorry... I was confused...

Comment: Write it in rectangular form.

Comment: @user204305 Do you mean that I have to use the following formula?? 
$$e^{(a+bi)x}=e^{a}(\cos {bx}+i \sin {bx})$$

Comment: That's one way. The other way is to solve $(x + iy)^2 = 2i$.

Comment: @user204305 Is it as followed?? 
$$\sqrt{2 i}=\sqrt{2 i\sin{\frac{\pi }{2}}}=\sqrt{2 \left ( \cos{\frac{\pi }{2}}+i \sin{\frac{\pi }{2}} \right )}=\sqrt{2e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}}=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$$

Comment: That's correct. Now write what $e^{\pi i /4}$ is.

Comment: @user204305 It is as followed: 
$$e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}=\cos {\frac{\pi}{4}}+i \sin {\frac{\pi }{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$ 
right??

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @user204305 $$\pm \sqrt{ 2i }a=\pm \sqrt{2}\left ( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right )a=\pm (1+i)a$$ That's why $$\pm \sqrt{ 2i }a\in \mathbb{Q}(a+ia)$$ right?$$\sqrt{-2 i}=\sqrt{-2 i\sin{\frac{\pi }{2}}}=\sqrt{2 \left ( \cos{\frac{3\pi }{2}}+i \sin{\frac{3\pi }{2}} \right )}=\sqrt{2e^{\frac{3\pi i}{2}}}=\sqrt{2}e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}}$$ 
$$e^{\frac{3\pi i}{4}}=\cos {\frac{3\pi}{4}}+i \sin {\frac{3\pi }{4}}=-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$ 
$$\pm \sqrt{- 2i }a=\pm \sqrt{2} \left ( -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right )a=\pm (-1+i)a$$Is $-a+ia\in \mathbb{Q}(a+ia)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. So this proves point 1 in my answer. However, I'll tell you now that there was an easier way to see this. That's that if $\alpha$ is a root of $x^4 + 20$, it's easy to see that $-\alpha$ must also be, as well as $\overline{\alpha}$, the complex conjugate of $\alpha$. And you already know $a + ia$ is a root.

Comment: @user204305 That means that since $a+ia$ is a root, the following elements are also roots: $$-(a+ia)=-a-ia, \ \ \overline{a+ia}=a-ia, \ \ \overline{-a-ia}=-a+ia$$ right??

Comment: Right. It's important to give an argument as to why $x^4 + 5$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Otherwise, you leave open the possibility that $a + ia$ could belong to $\mathbb{Q}(ia^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Prove this in three steps.

1. The four conjugates of $a + ia$ are $\pm a \pm ia$.
2. The normal closure of $\mathbb{Q}(a + ia)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(a,i)$. (If you don't know about normal closure, prove this instead: *If* $\mathbb{Q}(a + ia)$ were normal, it would be equal to $\mathbb{Q}(a,i)$.)
3. The degree of $\mathbb{Q}(a,i)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is greater than $4$.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on user204305's answer, let $N$ be a normal extension
of ${\mathbb Q}$ containing ${\mathbb Q}(a+ia)$. We have to show that
$N\neq {\mathbb Q}(a+ia)$.

As indicated in the OP, the minimal polynomial of $a+ia$ 
is $M=X^4+20$. The roots of $M$ are $m_1=a+ia$,
$m_2=im_1=-a+ia,m_3=-m_1=-a-ia$ and $m_4=-im_1=a-ia$.

By definition, $N$ contains all the $m_i$, so $N$
contains both $\frac{m_1+m_4}{2}=a$ and $\frac{m_1-m_4}{m_1+m_4}=i$. So
$N$ contains ${\mathbb Q}(a)$, and the inclusion is strict
(because ${\mathbb Q}(a) \subseteq {\mathbb R}$ and $i\in N$). We deduce
that $d=[N:{\mathbb Q}(a)]$ is $\geq 2$, so 
$[N:{\mathbb Q}]=[N:{\mathbb Q}(a)][{\mathbb Q}(a):{\mathbb Q}] \geq 8$ and hence
$N\neq {\mathbb Q}(a+ia)$ as wished.